# The play sound does not work when rotate the mobile

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I have my project to play sound. It worked well but when I rotate the mobile the sound doesn't work also it worked well when the app start. Also there isn't any error.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
        mp.start();
    } else {  
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your device is rotated, the current `Activity` gets recreated.  You likely need to hook into the `Activity` lifecycle events in order to properly manage the playing of your sound.  See the `onPause` and `onResume` methods explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the MediaPlayer instance in onCreate and start it in onResume(). Alternatively you can make your program work in only either portrait or landscape mode. This can be set in the manifest.

Comment: i added this  mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound); at oncreate and onresume but error "appication stopped ..." happened  @Override 
 protected void onResume() {
  
  
     super.onResume();
     mp.start();
 }