# how to stop the playing sound from interface by main activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I am beginner at Android App I have new app which call html files from assets file one of the task on this app is when user selected check box input to value "on" the mp3 play and when user goout from app as press back button or press home button the sound stopped and close the app. I did my interface between html and main activity to call java methods at html. When I added my code to stop the sound it does not play . I tried to add this line of code in main activity oncreate method .

```
mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
```

the sound stopped when press back or home or turnoff buttons . but the sound work when i open the app but this what i doesnot need i need this is when user select the checkbox . so how can i do it .

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     if(mp.isPlaying())
     mp.pause(); //stop the sound
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() 
 {
     super.onResume();
     mp.start();
 }
```

```
public class WebAppInterface   {
Context mContext;
 private MediaPlayer mp;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}


/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value  ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
        mp.setLooping(true);
  mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  mp.stop();}
}
}
```

Comment: -1 for creating multiple SO accounts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384958/error-the-application-stopped-when-press-mobile-logout-button/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350357/the-play-sound-does-not-work-when-rotate-the-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the issue is that the sound plays regardless whether you have selected the checkbox or not. A way to fix this would be to confirm whether the checkbox is checked or not in the onResume() method, instead of just starting regardless.

```
public class WebAppInterface extends Ramadan   {
Context mContext;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private static boolean checked = false;
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value , MediaPlayer mp ) {
     if (value.equals("on")) {
        checked = true;
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  
        checked = false;
        mp.stop();
    }
}
}
```

in your main class:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     if(mp.isPlaying())
     mp.pause(); //stop the sound
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() 
 {
     super.onResume();
     if(WebAppInterface.checked)
     {
         mp.start();
     }
 }
```

Comment: i have tow issues 1) when i removed static from  public boolean checked = false; the sound still work and no errors . 2) when i used  public boolean checked = false; with static the sound stopped when press lock button but when press on back or home button error " stopped application ..."